# Difference between mice::pool and mitools::MIcombine

Tags: imputation, r-mice

I can't figure out the difference between mitools::MIcombine and mice::pool.

I used the following code:
dsurvey<- svydesign(id =~0, data = imp_list, weights =~wgt)
MIcombine(with(dsurvey, svyquantile(~variable, c(0.25,0.5,0.75))))

Is this correct to get the median and interquartile range of my variable or should I be using pool() instead?

Thank you in advance.